# Does every code in header file A get included in header file B assuming those header files are in the same file

Tags: include

So lets say im in some file that has two header files A and B. I want to know if the stuff inside A.h gets included in B.h. In otherwords if A.h had a public function called getFoo() then would B.h be able to know what getFoo() is because its being included from A.h?

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if the stuff inside A.h gets included in B.h

No, it doesn’t (unless you have `#include "A.h"` inside `B.h` but you seem to imply that you don’t).

However, remember that inclusion is literally just textual substitution. This means that, whatever file you’ve shown in your question, includes both `A.h` and `B.h`. Therefore, *in this translation unit* declarations in `A.h` precede those in `B.h` and can therefore be used by code in `B.h`.

Answer (score 0):

You should include A.h header file in the B.h header file.

Comment: I understand including a in the b file does that but thats not my question lol